# Producing NDVI maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I'm trying to produce a simple NDVI map in QGIS using a Macbook pro (2011) from landsat raster images.

I've tried using the 'Measuring Vegetation' plugin, but for some reason that goes absolutely haywire as soon as I load it up, and I have to uninstall the plugin to use the system at all afterwards.

So I've tried doing it in the Raster Calculator plugin using exactly the same foruma as works perfectly in Grass GIS, namely

```
Float(band4 - band3)/ Float (band4 + band3)
```

I've tried it without float, with and without spaces between commands, with quotation marks around raster files.

All that is ever produced is a map that is uniform in tone (ie contains no information).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are achieving a calculation, but not displaying it graphically. So some things to try;

- the value tool plugin, should be available in the menu VIEW|PANELS|VALUETOOL  get this going and browse the map area, see if the values are there
- go to the properties of the new raster, and set a colour scale. Psuedocolour and FreakOut are there so as you can explore the data. Set a graduated colour scale when you start to get some idea what you want it to look like. There are preset colour scales for NDVI which work quite well. If you are on older versions of QGIS you can use the plugin for creating a colour scale.

If you aren't achieving a calculation, try the other raster calculator.

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me is

```
1.0 * (band4 - band3)/ (band4 + band3)
```

If the bands are separate rasters (and those are their names. Alternatively,

```
1.0 * ("RasterName@4" - "RasterName@3")/ ("RasterName@4" + "RasterName@3")
```

if they were loaded as one raster with separate bands.

I don't think the `float()` syntax works in QGIS expressions, but happy to be proven wrong (the raster calculator is actually borked on the current 3.10.3 Windows build, so I can't try it out now, but that shouldn't affect you on Mac). I'm actually not sure the `1.0 *` is still absolutely necessary, but it's a way to ensure conversion to float from inteeger.

The other answer(s) on how to display the resulting raster with a colour map, given its range is 0...1, are also important.